# The loop was functioning, but the screen wasn't

Tags: python, pygame

My question here is that after I pressed the start image, the figures, images and canvases appeared on the screen but it won't function at all. I checked whether each stage in the main program were functioning and it turned out that they were functioning. However, I wasn't able to detect the error here. I was suspicious towards the endgame() function, but wasn't sure where the problem was.

This is the start screen for the game, where you can click on the start image to start playing the game.

```
def start(): 
    global screen, canvas, clock, sound, random
    global player_1, x1, y1, score1
    global player_2, x2, y2, score2
    global starfish, s_x, s_y, starfish_list,starfish_quantity
    global rock, r_x, r_y
    global you_win,y_x,y_y
    global start_button, sb_x, sb_y

    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    screen.blit(canvas,[0,0])    
    screen.blit(start_button,[sb_x,sb_y])
    font_start=pygame.font.Font("DFTTNC5.TTC",50) #這個字體顯示數字有異常
    text_start=font_start.render("Turtle Battle!",True,[0,0,0])
    screen.blit(text_start,[sb_x-60,sb_y-80])

    if 214+sb_x >mouse[0]>sb_x and sb_y+114>mouse[1]>sb_y:
        if click[0]==1:
            mainloop()
    pygame.display.update()
```

This is the function to decide who wins in the end.

```
def End_Game():
    global screen, canvas, clock, sound, random
    global player_1, x1, y1, score1
    global player_2, x2, y2, score2
    global starfish, s_x, s_y, starfish_list,starfish_quantity
    global rock, r_x, r_y
    global you_win,y_x,y_y
    global start_button, sb_x, sb_y


    if len(starfish_list)==0 and score1>score2:
        font_w1 = pygame.font.Font("DFTTNC5.TTC",50)
        text_w1 = font_w1.render("Green Turtle", True, [134,53,20])
        screen.blit(text_w1,[y_x+40, y_y-40])
        screen.blit(you_win, [y_x,y_y])
        pygame.display.update()
        #time.sleep(10)
        return False

    elif len(starfish_list)==0 and score1<score2:
        font_w2 = pygame.font.Font("DFTTNC5.TTC",50)
        text_w2 = font_w2.render("Red Turtle", True, [134,53,20])
        screen.blit(text_w2,[y_x+40, y_y-40])
        screen.blit(you_win, [y_x,y_y])
        pygame.display.update()
        #time.sleep(10)
        return False
```

This is the mainloop for running the game, after breaking out the mainloop, the screen should be back to the start menu.

```
def mainloop():
    init()
    running = False
    while not running:
        CheckUserControl()
        Update_Screen()
        Object_Collision()
        if End_Game()==False:
            running = True
```

This is the main program. So after you initiate the game, you will start playing the game, and after deciding the winner, you should go back to the start menu. If you press quit, the program will be terminated.

```
renew = True  
init()      
while renew:
    start()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            renew = False
pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

It does not seem that you run `mainloop()` at all in the main gameloop. Add it and you should be fine.

EDIT: There are some other things you need to do too
First, remove the loop from the mainloop function, and add a gamestate variable to check if youre in the title or in the game.

```
renew = True  
init()      
while renew:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            renew = False
    if gamestate == 'Game':
        mainloop()
    elif gamestate == 'Title':
        title()
pygame.quit()
```

Also, I cringe about how many globals you have and are using, make a public.py file, put your variables in there, and import that into your script, not to mention the other poor code choices you made.